# HTTP ERROR 500 en mi web joomla

Tags: php, html

Recientemente hice una migración de mi web basa en joomla, de un hosting a otro. Migré tanto mi base de datos y mi pubic_html. El problema es que al migrarlos, la página me tira el "HTTP ERROR 500". Ya he probado con volver a migrarla y crear otro joomla y pasar los archivos, pero nada.
 en el log de errores del cpanel me aparece los siguiente:

> 2019-04-01 20:31:44.191995 [INFO] [186.83.208.126:49814] File not
>   found [/home/kbbayljn/alfonsoprudas.com/public_html/404.shtml]

Comment: 500 (Error interno del servidor)